Unrecognized optimizer and loss function in TensorFlow
I'm encountering an issue while trying to compile a Keras model in TensorFlow 2.15.0 using a custom optimizer and loss function, in google colab.
Here's the code snippet that works fine
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

However, when I attempt to configure the optimizer and loss separately as follows:
# Configure the optimizer, loss, and model
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
print(optimizer)
print(loss)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])

I encounter the following error:
ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <keras.src.optimizers.adam.Adam object at 0x7f925c90ace0>

It seems like TensorFlow is having trouble interpreting the custom optimizer object. Here are the details:
TensorFlow version: 2.15.0
Custom optimizer: <keras.src.optimizers.adam.Adam object at 0x7f925c90ace0>
Custom loss function: <keras.src.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy object at 0x7f9301977c10>


Are you mixing keras and tf.keras calls in your code?

double checked, i use import tensorflow as tf and tf.keras everywhere. thx

This what resolved the issue.

Check Installed Packages
 !pip list | grep keras

This returned unexpected "tf_keras"
 keras                            2.15.0
 tf_keras                         2.15.1


Uninstall "tf_keras"
 !pip uninstall tf_keras


Restart Runtime (Ctrl+M)

Verify Installed Packages.
 !pip list | grep keras

Should return only keras
 keras                            2.15.0




I can't reproduce your problem. When I run
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(weights=None)


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
print(optimizer)
print(loss)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.optimizer, model.loss)
print(tf.__version__)

it works well:
<keras.src.optimizers.adam.Adam object at 0x7f0944159990>
<keras.src.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy object at 0x7f08d03b5350>
<keras.src.optimizers.adam.Adam object at 0x7f0944159990> <keras.src.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy object at 0x7f08d03b5350>
2.15.0

